# Code Golf: Validate Sudoku Grid

Tags: algorithm, code-golf, sudoku

### Introduction

A valid Sudoku grid is filled with numbers 1 to 9, with no number occurring more than once in each sub-block of 9, row or column. Read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) for further details if you're unfamiliar with this popular puzzle.

### Challenge

The challenge is to write the shortest program that validates a Sudoku grid that might not be full.

Input will be a string of 9 lines of 9 characters each, representing the grid. An empty cell will be represented by a `.`. Your output should be `Valid` if the grid is valid, otherwise output `Invalid`.

### Example

#### Input

```
123...789
...456...
456...123
789...456
...123...
564...897
...231...
897...564
...564...
```

#### Output

```
Valid
```

#### Input

```
123456789
987654321
123456789
123456789
987654321
123456789
123456789
987654321
123456789
```

#### Output

```
Invalid
```

### Code Golf Rules

Please post your shortest code in any language that solves this problem. Input and output may be handled via stdin and stdout or by other files of your choice.

Winner will be the shortest solution (by byte count) in a language with an implementation existing prior to the posting of this question. So while you are free to use a language you've just made up in order to submit a 0-byte solution, it won't count, and you'll probably get downvotes.

Comment: What makes an incomplete puzzle invalid? Having multiple solutions? Having no solutions?

Comment: @Gabe A valid grid is defined in the intro, so e.g. a grid with two 1's in the first row is invalid.

Comment: Your intro says "A valid Sudoku grid is filled with numbers 1 to 9" but then you say that there can be empty cells. Since empty cells are not "numbers 1 to 9", that implies an incomplete puzzle is invalid. That is contrary to your example, so I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: @Gabe No need to check for solutions, validity is only defined by whether there are any illegal placements of numbers in the provided grid.

Comment: @marcog: You realise that a grid could meet those requirements and still have no solutions?  (E.g. imagine the top-left cell is blank, and the rest of the top row contains 2-9, while the rest of the leftmost column contains 1-8.  The top-left cell can't be 1 and 9 simultaneously.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker the goal is to reject a board if it's invalid on its face, not if it's unsolvable.

Comment: I bet there is a single perl regex for this in [nqueens-style](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=297616)...

Comment: Oh my god: 5 Perl solutions. Remind me, what for golf questions are CW?

Comment: Please commit to the new proposal for an own stackexchange platform for code-golfy and puzzly questions: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles?referrer=o0xSPrQt8RJqY44vShJFww2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Golfscript: 56

```
n%{zip''+9/.{'.'-..&=}%$0=\}:|2*{3/}%|;**"InvV"3/="alid"
```

Answer (score 9):

## C: <strike>165</strike> <strike>162</strike> <strike>161</strike> <strike>160</strike> 159

```
int v[1566],x,y=9,c,b;main(){while(y--)for(x=9;x--+1;)if((c
=getchar()*27)>1242)b|=v[x+c]++|v[y+9+c]++|v[x-x%3+y/3+18+c]
++;puts(b?"Invalid":"Valid");return 0;}
```

The two newlines are not needed. One char saved by josefx :-) ...

Comment: I tend to post a question: How can I learn to write code like this? Impressive.

Comment: @josefx: no... that wouldn't be equivalent. Equivalent would be `--x>-2` or `x-->=0` but they're of the same length. `x` must count from 8 to -1 (inclusive; 10th char is the newline) to be able to use `x-x%3` or `x/3*3` in the 3x3 block selector formula. I was thinking about changing the end part to `return 0>puts(...);`. That would make it a better citizen (i.e. returning a non-zero status code if puts fails) but still of the same length.

Comment: @6502 you are right, I don't know how I managed to mix up --x and x--.

Comment: my last try: replacing x-->-1; with x--+1;

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell: <strike>207</strike> <strike>230</strike> <strike>218</strike> <strike>195</strike> 172

```
import List
t=take 3
h=[t,t.drop 3,drop 6]
v[]="V"
v _="Inv"
f s=v[1|v<-[s,transpose s,[g=<<f s|f<-h,g<-h]],g<-map(filter(/='.'))v,g/=nub g]++"alid\n"
main=interact$f.lines
```

Comment: Oops, 207-char solution was incorrect: it was comparing groupings rather than individual rows/columns/blocks, and wasn't filtering out dots.

Comment: And again: replace `Data.List` by `List` and `Control.Monad` by `Monad`. Remove the let and put h as a top-level declaration. Change do-notation to explicit monads. But very nice, indeed.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Thanks, done.  Note that I still have to say `Control.Monad` because `replicateM` isn't available in [Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell98/latest/doc/html/Monad.html), only in [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html).

Comment: How about `replicate 9\`liftM\`getLine` instead of `replicateM`? And promote that lambda to a proper function, replacing if-than-else by pattern-guards. Usually shorter.

Comment: PS: You know, you can place all pattern guards onto a line, like: `f x|a=0|b=1`

Comment: @Joey Adams: You even can remove that import by `replicate 9`fmap`getLine`!

Comment: @FUZxxl: `replicate 9 \`liftM\` getLine` is not the same as `replicateM 9 getLine`.  Although they both have the same type `IO [String]`, the former only performs the action once, replicating its result 9 times.

Comment: @FUZxxl: However, I replaced `replicateM 9 getLine` with `getContents >>= … . lines`, saving 22 chars.  I also replaced the if/then with the `v` function and a pattern match, saving 1 char.

Comment: @Joey Adams: Sorry. Was too tired for this. How about `interact`?

Comment: I think it's also worth to make `take 3` an own function and to use `transpose` if possible.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Thanks, those certainly helped!  I was thinking of a `transpose` function when I wrote this, but didn't have a clue it was in the standard libraries.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl: <strike>168</strike> 128

```
$_=join'',<>;@a=/.../g;print+(/(\d)([^\n]{0,8}|(.{10})*.{9})\1/s
+map"@a[$_,$_+3,$_+6]"=~/(\d).*\1/,0..2,9..11,18..20)?Inv:V,alid
```

The first regex checks for duplicates that are in the same row and column; the second regex handles duplicates in the "same box".

Further improvement is possible by replacing the `\n` in the first regex with a literal newline (1 char), or with >= Perl 5.12, replacing `[^\n]` with `\N` (3 char)

Earlier, 168 char solution:
Input is from stdin, output is to *stderr* because it makes things so easy. Linebreaks are optional and not counted.

```
$_=join'',<>;$m=alid.$/;$n=Inv.$m;/(\d)(\N{0,8}|(.{10})*.{9})\1/s&&
die$n;@a=/.../g;for$i(0,8,17){for$j($i..$i+2){
$_=$a[$j].$a[$j+3].$a[$j+6];/(\d).*\1/&&die$n}}die"V$m"
```

Comment: I get an error message "Constant(\N{0,8}) unknown: (possibly a missing "use charnames ...")" on my Perl v5.10.0.  Looking at the definition of `\N`, it appears to be for "named unicode characters" -- how are you trying to use it here?

Comment: @j_random_hacker in the way that happens to only work on 5.12.0+, as it turns out :) It means "anything but newline", that is the same thing that `.` means when `/s` is disabled, except it works regardless of `/s`.

Answer (score 4):

### Python: <strike>230</strike> <strike>221</strike> <strike>200</strike> 185

First the readable version at len=199:

```
import sys
r=range(9)
g=[raw_input()for _ in r]
s=[[]for _ in r*3]
for i in r:
 for j in r:
  n=g[i][j]
  for x in i,9+j,18+i/3*3+j/3:
<T>if n in s[x]:sys.exit('Invalid')
<T>if n>'.':s[x]+=n
print'Valid'
```

Since SO doesn't display tab characters, I've used `<T>` to represent a single tab character.

PS. the same approach minEvilized down to 185 chars:

```
r=range(9)
g=[raw_input()for _ in r]
s=['']*27
for i in r:
 for j in r:
    for x in i,9+j,18+i/3*3+j/3:n=g[i][j];s[x]+=n[:n>'.']
print['V','Inv'][any(len(e)>len(set(e))for e in s)]+'alid'
```

Comment: replaced list of digits w/string of digits (since they are 1..9) and that allowed for some shortening of the code. readability suffered though

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 153 char

`@B` contains the 81 elements of the board.

`&E` tests whether a subset of `@B` contains any duplicate digits

main loop validates each column, "block", and row of the puzzle

```
sub E{$V+="@B[@_]"=~/(\d).*\1/}
@B=map/\S/g,<>;
for$d(@b=0..80){
E grep$d==$_%9,@b;
E grep$d==int(($_%9)/3)+3*int$_/27,@b;
E$d*9..$d*9+8}
print$V?Inv:V,alid,$/
```

Comment: I can also get hobbs algorithm down to 136 chars.

Comment: I like the array slice of `@B` in `E`.

Answer (score 3):

### Python: <strike>159</strike> 158

```
v=[0]*244
for y in range(9):
 for x,c in enumerate(raw_input()):
  if c>".":
<T>for k in x,y+9,x-x%3+y//3+18:v[k*9+int(c)]+=1
print["Inv","V"][max(v)<2]+"alid"
```

<T> is a single tab character

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp: <strike>266</strike> 252

```
(princ(let((v(make-hash-table))(r "Valid"))(dotimes(y 9)(dotimes(x
10)(let((c(read-char)))(when(>(char-code c)46)(dolist(k(list x(+ 9
y)(+ 18(floor(/ y 3))(- x(mod x 3)))))(when(>(incf(gethash(+(* k
9)(char-code c)-49)v 0))1)(setf r "Invalid")))))))r))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl: 186

Input is from stdin, output to stdout, linebreaks in input optional.

```
@y=map/\S/g,<>;
sub c{(join'',map$y[$_],@$h)=~/(\d).*\1/|c(@_)if$h=pop}
print(('V','Inv')[c map{$x=$_;[$_*9..$_*9+8],[grep$_%9==$x,0..80],[map$_+3*$b[$x],@b=grep$_%9<3,0..20]}0..8],'alid')
```

(Linebreaks added for "clarity".)

`c()` is a function that checks the input in `@y` against a list of lists of position numbers passed as an argument.  It returns 0 if all position lists are valid (contain no number more than once) and 1 otherwise, using recursion to check each list.  The bottom line builds this list of lists, passes it to `c()` and uses the result to select the right prefix to output.

One thing that I quite like is that this solution takes advantage of "self-similarity" in the "block" position list in `@b` (which is redundantly rebuilt many times to avoid having `@b=...` in a separate statement): the top-left position of the ith block within the entire puzzle can be found by multiplying the ith element in `@b` by 3.

More spread out:

```
# Grab input into an array of individual characters, discarding whitespace
@y = map /\S/g, <>;

# Takes a list of position lists.
# Returns 0 if all position lists are valid, 1 otherwise.
sub c {
    # Pop the last list into $h, extract the characters at these positions with
    # map, and check the result for multiple occurences of
    # any digit using a regex.  Note | behaves like || here but is shorter ;)
    # If the match fails, try again with the remaining list of position lists.
    # Because Perl returns the last expression evaluated, if we are at the
    # end of the list, the pop will return undef, and this will be passed back
    # which is what we want as it evaluates to false.
    (join '', map $y[$_], @$h) =~ /(\d).*\1/ | c(@_) if $h = pop
}

# Make a list of position lists with map and pass it to c().
print(('V','Inv')[c map {
        $x=$_;                  # Save the outer "loop" variable
        [$_*9..$_*9+8],         # Columns
        [grep$_%9==$x,0..80],   # Rows
        [map$_+3*$b[$x],@b=grep$_%9<3,0..20]   # Blocks
    } 0..8],                    # Generates 1 column, row and block each time
'alid')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl: 202

I'm reading Modern Perl and felt like coding something... (quite a cool book by the way:)

```
while(<>){$i++;$j=0;for$s(split//){$j++;$l{$i}{$s}++;$c{$j}{$s}++;
$q{(int(($i+2)/3)-1)*3+int(($j+2)/3)}{$s}++}}
$e=V;for$i(1..9){for(1..9){$e=Inv if$l{$i}{$_}>1or$c{$i}{$_}>1or$q{$i}{$_}>1}}
print $e.alid
```

Count is excluding unnecessary newlines.
This may require Perl 5.12.2.

A bit more readable:

```
#use feature qw(say);
#use JSON;

#$json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;

while(<>)
{
    $i++;
    $j=0;
    for $s (split //)
    {
        $j++;
        $l{$i}{$s}++;
        $c{$j}{$s}++;
        $q{(int(($i+2)/3)-1)*3+int(($j+2)/3)}{$s}++;
    }
}

#say "lines: ", $json->pretty->encode( \%l );
#say "columns: ", $json->pretty->encode( \%c );
#say "squares: ", $json->pretty->encode( \%q );

$e = V;
for $i (1..9)
{
    for (1..9)
    {
        #say "checking {$i}{$_}: " . $l{$i}{$_} . " / " . $c{$i}{$_} . " / " . $q{$i}{$_};
        $e = Inv if $l{$i}{$_} > 1 or $c{$i}{$_} > 1 or $q{$i}{$_} > 1;
    }
}

print $e.alid;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby — 176

```
f=->x{x.any?{|i|(i-[?.]).uniq!}}
a=[*$<].map{|i|i.scan /./}
puts f[a]||f[a.transpose]||f[a.each_slice(3).flat_map{|b|b.transpose.each_slice(3).map &:flatten}]?'Invalid':'Valid'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Lua, 341 bytes**

Although I know that Lua isn't the best golfing language, however, considering it's size, I think it's worth posting it ;).
Non-golfed, commented and error-printing version, for extra fun :)

```
i=io.read("*a"):gsub("\n","")   -- Get input, and strip newlines
a={{},{},{}} -- checking array, 1=row, 2=columns, 3=squares
for k=1,3 do for l=1,9 do a[k][l]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}end end -- fillup array with 0's (just to have non-nils)

for k=1,81 do -- loop over all numbers
    n=tonumber(i:sub(k,k):match'%d') -- get current character, check if it's a digit, and convert to a number
    if n then
        r={math.floor((k-1)/9)+1,(k-1)%9+1} -- Get row and column number
        r[3]=math.floor((r[1]-1)/3)+3*math.floor((r[2]-1)/3)+1 -- Get square number
        for l=1,3 do v=a[l][r[l]] -- 1 = row, 2 = column, 3 = square
            if v[n] then -- not yet eliminated in this row/column/square
                v[n]=nil    
            else
                print("Double "..n.." in "..({"row","column","square"}) [l].." "..r[l]) --error reporting, just for the extra credit :)
                q=1 -- Flag indicating invalidity
            end
        end
    end
end
io.write(q and"In"or"","Valid\n")
```

Golfed version, 341 bytes

```
f=math.floor p=io.write i=io.read("*a"):gsub("\n","")a={{},{},{}}for k=1,3 do for l=1,9 do a[k][l]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}end end for k=1,81 do n=tonumber(i:sub(k,k):match'%d')if n then r={f((k-1)/9)+1,(k-1)%9+1}r[3]=f((r[1]-1)/3)+1+3*f((r[2]-1)/3)for l=1,3 do v=a[l][r[l]]if v[n]then v[n]=nil else q=1 end end end end p(q and"In"or"","Valid\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python: 140

```
v=[(k,c) for y in range(9) for x,c in enumerate(raw_input()) for k in x,y+9,(x/3,y/3) if c>'.']
print["V","Inv"][len(v)>len(set(v))]+"alid"
```

Answer (score 1):

### ASL: 108

```
args1["\n"x2I3*x;{;{:=T(T'{:i~{^0}?})}}
{;{;{{,0:e}:;{0:^},u eq}}/`/=}:-C
dc C@;{:|}C&{"Valid"}{"Invalid"}?P
```

ASL is a Golfscript inspired scripting language I made.